# JaCoCo check goal for integration tests

Tags: jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

My belief is that JaCoCo Maven plugins [`check`](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html) goal does not support integration tests in a multi module project (where the integration tests are in a different module to the code under test).

I have a project with the following structure:

```
service
├── webapp
├── lib1
├── lib2
└── integration-test
```

`webapp` depends on `lib1` and `lib2` and builds to a WAR, `integration-test` uses an in memory container to run `webapp` and execute tests against it.

My configuration is such that JaCoCo is successfully generating consolidated data files (`jacoco.exec` and  `jacoco-it.exec` in `service/target/`) for unit tests in {`webapp`, `lib1`, `lib2`} AND integration test coverage for the tests run in `integration-test`.

When adding in the configuration for `check` I get this output from the plugin.

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.8:check (default-check) @ integration-test ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing classes directory:/home/mark/workspace/service/integration-test/target/classes
```

The error is accurate, as the `integration-test` module has only test source, so there is no `target/classes` directory. Adding a source directory didn't help, `check` failed indicating 0% coverage because there was no applicable class files in the `target/classes` directory.
From this (and looking at the [check Mojo source](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/blob/master/jacoco-maven-plugin/src/org/jacoco/maven/CheckMojo.java)) it seems the `check` goal requires the `classes` directories of all the modules that it is instrumenting (`webapp`, `lib1`, `lib2`).

No such configuration exists in [`check`](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html) that allows me to specify where the `classes` directories nor does it looks like it supports such a feature looking at the source.

Root / parent `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
    <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco-it.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
</properties>

<-- Note, I am using build/plugins/plugin - not build/pluginManagement/plugin

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.8</version>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>agent-for-ut</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <append>true</append>
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>agent-for-it</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <append>true</append>
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</destFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-check</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <configuration>
                <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.itReportPath}</dataFile>
                <rules>
                    <rule>
                        <element>BUNDLE</element>
                        <limits>
                            <limit>
                                <counter>LINE</counter>
                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                <minimum>0.9800</minimum>
                            </limit>
                        </limits>
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

`integration-test pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                <argLine>${argLine} -Duser.timezone=UTC -Xms256m -Xmx256m</argLine>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems like this would be something a lot of people would run into. Did you ever find a solution for this?